# Significantly longer transaction confirmation time for large v0 transactions

Tags: versionedtransactions, confirmation, priority-fees

I've been using v0 transactions for about two months, but recently (possibly due to BONK related congestion) the transactions have been taking much longer to confirm and frequently drop all together.

The transactions in question increase compute by about 800k, I'm mostly looking for guidance on how to think about these transactions and ways to speed up the confirmation.

Repo with sample implementation of a transaction in question below.

https://github.com/elixirfi/nft-trade-integrations/blob/a7a738a1a450791b4ceadedc1811d6dd9f338a67/functions/buy.ts#L247

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still haven't figured out the specifics but the temporary work around was trimming compute as much as possible and tremendously increasing priority fees. Trying to understand how validators are picking txns, but in the meantime this works.